# Host header not being applied

Tags: axios

I am confused. I've added headers to a request before and, for some reason, this one does not work as I want it to.

I'm trying to perform a post request to Linkedin following their documentation to get an access_token from an OAuth2 flow. I have the preliminary code to pass to the token endpoint, that is not an issue.

This is the sample request from the docs:

[image]

POST /oauth/v2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: [www.linkedin.com](http://www.linkedin.com)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code={authorization_code_from_step2_response}&redirect_uri=hhttps%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}

[image]

I assume the Host header is to avoid CORS issues, but it just isnt being set. When I perform this request, my console gives me this 404:

[image]

Given that I know the Header is not 'unsafe', how do I go about setting it in this specific case?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Remove the Host header from config object and set it directly in the URL. Works just fine. I now have CORS Allow-Origin issues, but that's not related.